# Guardar un archivo leído de una URL con NSInputStream

Tags: ios, objective-c

Quiero guardar un archivo al que accedo mediante una URL.

Para ello uso `NSInputStream` y `NSOutputStream`:

```
self.fileStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:self.filePath append:NO]; 
[self.fileStream open];
self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(CFReadStreamCreateWithFile(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)); // path

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)[url host], 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
self.networkStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;

self.networkStream.delegate = self;
[self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.networkStream open];
```

El problema es que me devuelve un código de evento `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted` y no un `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` que utilizaría para escribir el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

¿Estás usando `NSInputStream` y `NSOutputStream` por algún motivo en particular? Una solución mucho más simple sería usar `NSData`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
BOOL result = [data writeToFile:self.ilePath atomically:YES];
```

Ten en cuenta que este código no se debe ejecutar en el *main thread* para no bloquear la UI. Deberías ejecutarlo en un *thread* en *background*.

Comment: Lo uso por tema de compatibilidad con un código que ya tengo escrito. Si en vez de acceder por url accedo por ftp el código funciona cambiando solo la línea de CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost por la homologa a FTP y luego devuelve un código de evento NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable donde implemento el método de guardar archivo.